# Query max date in elasticsearch

Tags: go, elasticsearch, aggregate

I need to get in Go the latest date from a datetime field of the elasticsearch index's documents. Basically, I have this query that I do directly in the elasticsearch that returns me just what I need:

```
GET localhost:9200/index-name/_search

    {
        "aggs" : {
           "max_date": {"max": {"field": "dateTime"}}
        }
    }
```

I need to do that same query in Go. I saw that there is a MaxAgregation in Olivere library, but I'm not sure about how to use it. Does someone knows how to do that?

Comment: [The language is called Go. Not GO. Not GOlang](https://www.reddit.com/r/golang/comments/30wsrs/the_name_of_our_language_is_go/)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how [to get started](https://olivere.github.io/elastic/#getting-started) w/ the go library.

After you instantiate a `client`, you can do the following:

```
maxDateAgg := NewMaxAggregation().Field("dateTime")

builder := client.Search().Index("index-name").Pretty(true)
builder = builder.Aggregation("max_date", maxDateAgg)
```

After that, call `.Do(ctx)` on the `builder`.

Comment: Thanks! I manage to make it work with your answer and some things that I already had:

maxDateAgg := elastic.NewMaxAggregation().Field("dateTime")

 builder := esClient.Search().Index("index-name").Pretty(true)
 builder = builder.Aggregation("max_datetime", maxDateAgg)
 builder = builder.Size(1).Sort("dateTime",false)
 searchResult, err := builder.Do(ctx)
       
This returns all the fields, so I made a Struct, and json.unmarshall the search.hit.hit source into the struct, so i could take only the datetime.

Thanks again!

Comment: Sounds good. Feel free to upvote & accept if it helped you :-)

Answer (score 0):

I manage to make it work with one of the answers and some things that I already had:

```
maxDateAgg := elastic.NewMaxAggregation().Field("dateTime") 

builder := esClient.Search().Index("index-name").Pretty(true) 
builder = builder.Aggregation("max_datetime", maxDateAgg) builder = builder.Size(1).Sort("dateTime",false) 

searchResult, err := builder.Do(ctx)
```

This returns all the fields from the documents with the max datetime, so I made a Struct, and json.unmarshall the search.hit.hit source into the struct, so i could take only the datetime field from the struct.

Answer (score 0):

For those wondering how to get the date

```golang
ctx := context.Background()

termQuery := elastic.NewMatchAllQuery()
agg := elastic.NewMaxAggregation().Field("le_nested.last_updated")
sr, err := elastic.Client.Search("your_index").Query(termQuery).Aggregation("max_date", agg).Do(ctx)
if err != nil {
    m := fmt.Sprint("Error getting getting last updated data", err)
    fmt.Println(m)
}

max, found := sr.Aggregations.MaxBucket("max_date")
if !found {
    m := fmt.Sprint("max_date aggregation not found", err)
    fmt.Println(m)
}
fmt.Println("MAX DATE", max.ValueAsString)
tm := int64(*max.Value) / 1000
mu := time.Unix(tm, 0)
fmt.Println("DATE", mu)
```

ES returns the dates in millis, no need to unmarshall anything